# length of string limit about SQL server jdbc?

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

I come across a issue that would cause SQL injection to SQL server, but a comment wrote there say that SQL server's JDBC driver would truncate the string if its length is greater to 254 while using prepared statement's setString() function because it converts string to SQL_Char. This seem like a real problematic issue but I'm not sure if it does exist.

Does anyone know any official doc that stated this issue and when they have fixed it since which version?

---

### UPDATE

He's using this old and dangerous way to do insert

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO TABLE(field1, field2) VALUES('" + val1 + "','" + val2 +"')";
```

val1 and val2 would represent a long string that its length is greater than 254. But this SQLi isn't what I wanna ask.

Comment: You might want to include more details about the injection attack in question.  Length by itself does not necessarily affect injection.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen added. but SQLi isn't my question but string length limit of PreparesStatement.setString()

Comment: Seem like none knows about the setString() issue. can't wait and gotta move onto next work